# Access PrivateKey in x509 certificate in windows certificate store marked non-exportable

Tags: c#, private-key, x509certificate2, certificate-store

I've managed to access the certificates collection and target the specific certificate by thumbprint. I can access all its properties, and its "HasPrivateKey" is set to true.

The "Exportable" in the CspKeyContainerInfo is marked as false.

When I do a PrivateKey.ToXmlString(false) meaning I do not get the key parameters but just the Modulus and Exponent its fine:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>4hjg1ibWXHIlH...ssmlBfMAListzrgk=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

but if I set it to toXmlString(true) to get all the values it fails:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>4hjg1ibWXHIlH...ssmlBfMAListzrgk=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    <P>8QZCtrmJcr9uW7VRex+diH...jLHV5StmuBs1+vZZAQ==</P>
    <Q>8CUvJTv...yeDszMWNCQ==</Q>
    <DP>elh2Nv...cygE3657AQ==</DP>
    <DQ>MBUh5XC...+PfiMfX0EQ==</DQ>
    <InverseQ>oxvsj4WCbQ....LyjggXg==</InverseQ>
    <D>KrhmqzAVasx...uxQ5VGZmZ6yOAE=</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

However if I re-import the certificate and mark it "Exportable", then the above gives me access to all the KeyInformation I need to proceed.

Is there a way to keep a key Non-Exportable, and still access the information with toXmlString(true) programatically by using x509....Certiificate2 object?

```
   X509Certificate2Collection xcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "4678237245FEDC8059D113675955DFB870D36BF4", false);

        foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in xcollection)
        {
            var y = x509.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(false);
            var f = x509.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
        }
```

Cheers

Comment: no, it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks CryptoGuy, do you know of any 3rd party tools that can do this? Or is this just the way it is and maybe should be?

Comment: the whole purpose of this flag is key protection from export in plain text and CSP will not give you key if it is not allowed for export.

Comment: Is there another way in the .NET framework to read a private key marked NOT-EXPORTABLE from a certificate in the certificate store?

Comment: did you read my first reply?

Comment: CryptoGuy - Yes I read it thanks, but what I am asking is if it is possible to ie. do something like this instead:

 X509Certificate2 cert

(RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey

And get it that way instead of using the ToXmlString(true) method

Comment: What do you need ToXmlString for? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Pepo - I want to use the privatekey XmlString to pass into the RSA.FromXmlString(xxx) method -  in order to decrypt

Comment: `ToXmlString` is just a format to store private key. And why you can't use existing private key instance to decrypt the data?

Comment: CryptoGuy - I have not tried to pass the cert.PrivateKey to the RSA object yet. But I know that the ToXmlString doesnt work with a key marked as Non-Exportable, so I just wanted to know if the other approach would work before going further with it. I mean if the key is marked as Non-Exportable, can it then be used as PrivateKey instance to decrypt passing it along with the RSACryptoServiceProvider?